# Telerik RadEditor not picking up the current content

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I have an aspx page with a drop down list and a Telrik RadEditor on it, the drop down list populates the editor with a text template on the selected index changed event of the ddl.

When the user edits the text in the template and tries to save it, it only saves the original text, but if the user changes the drop down list to nothing, the template text remains and then if they update  the template it saves the new content.

Can anyone tell me how to make sure the current content of the editor is saved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more likely related to overriding the editor content yourself, in the Page_Load method. Please note that if you read the content of the editor in an event handler (such as a button event handler) this event handler executes later in the page lifecycle compared to Page_Load. This is why, in case you set the initial content in Page_Load it is mandatory to add a check, e.g.

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    RadEditor1.Content = "Some content";
}

In case you are having any difficulty, you can implement your scenario using a simple  instead of RadEditor. Once you get the textbox to work as needed, all you need to do is change the textbox to RadEditor - and all should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

To save content of RadEditor you have to use

```
txtDescription.Content
```

Comment: Yea, but when the text is changed it's still picking up the old text not the new text

Comment: On change of dropdown are you rebinding your editor?

Comment: the ddl is pulling data from a db based on the selected value and then setting the content of the editor to the returned text..... txtTemplate.Content = record.Description; that is the extent of the binding

Comment: is there code for binding dropdown and Editor is inside PostBack.? Means when you click on Savebutton, check if its rebinding your control.